# Powershell IIS Audit Scripting

Tags: powershell, iis, scripting, audit

I'm in the early stages of learning powershell, and I'm trying to put together a script that remotely gathers information from our IIS servers, but I'm encountering several issues.

The first one is that the IP Address and OU columns remain empty in the output file.
The second one is that I'm not able to format the Administrator group column to have 1 group per line, or delimited by commas.

This is the current version of the code:

```
$computers = Get-Content "C:\servers.txt"


#Running the invoke-command on remote machine to run the iisreset


$output = foreach ($computer in $computers) 
{
       Write-Host "Details from server $computer..."

    try{
           Invoke-command  -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock{

           # Ensure to import the WebAdministration and AD module

                Import-Module WebAdministration
                Import-Module ActiveDirectory

                $webapps = Get-WebApplication
                $list = @()
                foreach ($webapp in get-childitem IIS:\AppPools\)
                {
                    $name = "IIS:\AppPools\" + $webapp.name
                    $item = @{}
                    $item.server = $env:computername
                    $item.WebAppName = $webapp.name
                    $item.Version = (Get-ItemProperty $name managedRuntimeVersion).Value
                    $item.State = (Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $webapp.name).Value
                    $item.UserIdentityType = $webapp.processModel.identityType
                    $item.Username = $webapp.processModel.userName
                    $item.Password = $webapp.processModel.password
                    $item.OU = (Get-ADComputer $_ | select DistinguishedNAme)
                    $item.IPAddress = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4)
                    $item.Administrators = (Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators")



                    $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property $item
                    $list += $obj
                }



                $list | select -Property "Server","WebAppName", "Version", "State", "UserIdentityType", "Username", "Password", "OU", "Ip Address", "Administrators"

        }

    } catch {
        Add-Content .\failedservers.txt -Force -Value $computer
    }
} 

$output | Export-Csv -Path .\output.csv
#Stop-Transcript
```

I'd really appreciate any input on how to get it to work properly or improve on the code itself.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For the `OU` property, you'll want to reference `$env:COMPUTERNAME` instead of `$_`:

```
$item.OU = (Get-ADComputer $env:COMPUTERNAME |Select -Expand DistinguishedName)
```

For the `IPAddress` and `Administrators` fields you'll want to use `-join` to create comma-separated lists of the relevant values:

```
$item.IPAddress = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4).IPAddress -join ','
$item.Administrators = (Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators").Name -join ','
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and help.

I've tried your solution, and it partially works.
I can get the members of the admin group separated by commas, but the IP and OU fields are still turning out empty on the CSV file.

Comment: @DiegoS. Updated the first example (use `-Expand` to get just the property value) You might want to `Import-Module NetTCPIP` in the remote scriptblock to make `Get-NetIPAddress` work

Comment: I've tried your update, but it still doesn't complete the fields for the IP and OU.